# Как не хранить последовательность в данном случае? Язык С++ или С

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия

Всем привет, вот такой вопрос. На языке С или С++ нужно написать программу с рекурсией и без нее, используя рекурсивную и итеративную функции. Как можно не хранить в данном случае последовательность?

Найти номер последнего вхождения минимального значения в
последовательность длины n. Последовательность не хранить.

Comment: `if(arr[i] <= min) { min = arr[i]; min_i = i; } ` весь секрет в `=`. Точней не `arr[i]` а символ который ввели последний

Comment: *"Как можно не хранить в данном случае последовательность"* Понятно как. Уложиться в один цикл, и прямо в цикле читать по одному числу и сразу обрабатывать их.

Comment: Это-то понятно, только вот проблема в чем. Допустим, итеративная функция далась довольно быстро и ясно, а как в данном случае поступать с рекурсией? Надо ж как-то присвоить значение для переменной min, и чтобы это было не в самой функции. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Причём итеративную функцию я сделал именно таким методом, да, радует один ход мыслей, спасибо

Comment: Нужно в рекурсивной функции вводить элементы (по другому честно только многопоточность в голову приходит). По значению можете передавать кол-во элементов, по ссылке `min` и все! Вводите число проверяете на `min` вызываете рекурсивно эту функцию передавая `размер - 1` и `min` Если `размер == 0` просто выходите из функции. Все! В качестве `min` можете или `INT32_MIN` (ну если у вас тип `int`) или присвоить ему просто первое вводимое число.

Comment: @IBuyPower31 Если у вас половина задания уже сделана, то советую показывать ее вместе с задачей, когда постите вопрос. Вам будут охотнее помогать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да просто передавать все нужное через аргументы.

Что-то типа (писалось на коленке, но вроде должно компилироваться)

```
int getMin(int n, int No = 0, int min_idx = -1, int min_value = 0)
{
    if (No == n) return min_idx;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if (min_idx == -1)
    {
        min_idx = 0;
        min_value = x;
    }
    else if (x <= min_value)
    {
        min_idx = No;
        min_value = x;
    }
    return getMin(n,No+1,min_idx,min_value);
}
```

Вызов - просто `getMin(n)`, нумерация элементов с 0, считывание из `cin`. Для своих (не описанных вами) требований перепишите сами, это несложно :)

Comment: Премного благодарен. Ваша программа открыла глаза и я понял, что делал не так ранее. Большое спасибо! Всё работает :)

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - то рядом с ним есть такая птичка, которая позволяет его принять...